# How to program conditional statements for this problem in r

Tags: r, corpus

*Situation*: I'm trying to program the following in r.

*Task*: I am trying to select for words that appear as nouns in my dataset more than they do as adjectives, verbs, or adverbs etc. I have all these counts and below is an example of one instance of what I am trying to do. Imagine the information below is in a dataframe. I do not want to select for this lemma (ability), because it appears most times as a VERB; i.e., its appearance as a noun is not greater than VERB or ADJ:

```
id <- (c(4, 4, 4))
lemma <- (c("ability", "ability", "ability"))
count_lemma+pos <- (21, 66, 89332)
pos <- ("ADJ", "NOUN", "VERB)
```

*Action*: I tried to start programming the fail below to get to the following logic:

1. group the data by id
2. for every row i id, check if pos == "NOUN"
3. If not, then delete the row in id
4. check id for max value
5. return pos
6. pos != "NOUN", then delete id

```
#This is my failed attempt at the first step in r:

noun_count_all <- ddply(noun_count, .(lemma), function(noun_count) {
  filter1 <- filter(noun_count, pos=="NOUN")
  #filter2 <-
  return(filter1)
} )
```

*Result*: Not getting anywhere. If I've written this question incorrectly, sorry about that. Not a programmer or data scientist, I'm just trying to use R to do this thing I can't do in excel.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean with almost all of your steps except 4 and 5. What do you want to do with the `id` column, just see the max value or filter on rows where the `id` is equal to the maximum `id` within the group? And for 5, you want to return all values for `pos` column or filtered on something?

Comment: My apologies @Oxbowerce that steps 4 + 5 were not clear. In step 4, I really just want to check whether the row in the group (which I can group by `id` or `lemma`) with the highest value (e.g., out of 1 4 6 it would be 6) is a noun. This is linked to step 5. Step 5 is not so necessary, but was more to manually chceck inside the loop if I wanted to. Then step 6 is saying: please delete all of the rows containing highest values, in the group, which are not nouns. Does that make more sense?

Comment: p.s. I am trying to filter for all "NOUN" in `pos` which are the highest value in each group by `id`; if note then delete.

Comment: I think so, but just to be sure can you provide the expected output given the inputs you provided? Also, how can you remove rows where `pos != "NOUN"` if you already filtered out those rows in step 2/3?

Comment: Yeah, so given the inputs above the `lemma` "ability or you could think of it as the `id` 4 would be removed from the final data frame because it is not the highest value in the distribution of its set. Step 2/3 was a convoluted way of getting rid of any id sets which did not have any nouns in them. Very inefficient in hindsight...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, the following code selects only the rows where the `pos` column has the value `"NOUN"` and where the `count_lemma+pos` is the highest within the group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    # group by id
    groupby(id) %>%
    # filter on rows where pos == "NOUN" and count_lemma_pos is the max value within the group
    filter(pos == "NOUN" & count_lemma_pos == max(count_lemma_pos))
```

Comment: That is it! It is ridiculous how much I complicated things compared to how simple the solution is. Thank you so much @Oxbowerce. I hope this is helpful for other people too.

Comment: No worries, if it solved your problem make sure to mark this as the answer so other know the solution as well.

Comment: Thank you @Oxbowerce, I really appreciate your help and hope I learn to be more efficient in the future.